# Want to use multiple layouts to load data

Tags: java, android

I want to use multiple frames to load the app data. I just want to know, what the right way to do this is. Should I use frame layouts or I have to use fragment. I am also using navigation drawer in my app.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.homepage) {
            Intent homepage = new Intent (MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(homepage);
                            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.foodpage) {
            //handle the food page here
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new FirstFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.schedulepage) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new ScheduleFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.emotionspage) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                    , new EmotionsFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.basicneedspage) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frametwo
                    , new BasicneedsFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.exit) {
            askBeforeExit();

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You better using fragment for that. Fragment puts less load in main thread. while as in case of frame layout you have to manage lot of things.

Comment: See, right now i am using frame layouts. but the problem is both the frames showing data at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LayoutInflater for these kind of things where you are working on multiple layouts in same activity.

Comment: Ok. can you please give the method or codes for LayoutInflater. how can i implement in my main file.

Comment: LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutitem);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.childlayout, null);
item.addView(child);

Comment: You want to say here is, I have to create two layout files separately. Can I set the set visibility method in the main java file?